# проблема с git при клонировании - early EOF

Tags: linux, git, gitlab, git-clone

Доброго дня!
Имеется сервер gitlab+gitlab-ci+gitlab-ci-runner

```
System information
System:     Ubuntu 15.04
GitLab information
Version:    7.0.0
Revision:   d1e424b
GitLab Shell
Version:    1.9.6
Gitab CI Runner
v5.0.0
Gitab CI
v5.0.1
```

Билды по всем проектам собираются, кроме одного. После запуска сборки по этому проекту вылетает ошибка следующего плана (на этапе клонирования)

```
git clone http://[[GitLab - URL]]/[[Group]]/[[Project]].git [[Project]]
Cloning into '[[Project]]'...
remote: Counting objects: 13035, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (10177/10177), done.
error: RPC failed; result=18, HTTP code = 200B | 6.17 MiB/s   
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Что было сделано:

1. `config/unicorn.rb` - timeout 120
2. `config/gitlab.yml` - max_size: 524288000, timeout: 120
3. `git config --global -l`

   ```
   [core]
       compression = -1 (и compression = 0)
   [http]
       postBuffer = 524288000
   [core]
       packedGitLimit = 512m
       packedGitWindowSize = 512m
   [pack]
       deltaCacheSize = 1024m
       packSizeLimit = 1024m
       windowMemory = 1024m
   ```

Все безрезультатно! В логах ничего подозрительного нет. Вербос при клонировании аналогично никакой информации не выдает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Возможно, размер репозитория превышает размер доступной памяти сервера. Какого размера ваш и сколько доступно памяти? 

[git clone fails with "index-pack" failed?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10027105)

Comment: а *bare*-репозиторий удаётся создать? `git clone --bare ...`

Comment: --bare аналогично вываливается с той же ошибкой :(

Comment: Памяти более чем достаточно - дело в том что если клонировать напрямую из репозитория (без gitlab-ci-token) то все проходит без ошибков

Comment: Пока что новых идей нет, удалил ответ.

Comment: Убил все процессы гитлаба, перезапустил редис - в итоге проект собрался. Но проблема перекинулась на некоторые другие проекты ... что не так не понимаю

Comment: sidekiq 2.17.0 gitlab [0 of 25 busy]

Comment: Похоже разобрался - додумался глянуть в логи nginx-а и увидел там источник моей проблемы :) Прав не хватало директории /var/lib/nginx/proxy... мда

Comment: @Николай: раз уж вы разобрались с такой необычной проблемой — не могли бы вы сами ответ написать? Сэкономите кому-нибудь ещё несколько часов битья головой о стену )

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: тут автор нашел решение, может быть вам будет интересно.